# How to pass php variables via jquery

Tags: jquery

i have one image upload script and i want to pass php variables via jquery

this is my jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function() {      
    $('#form_data').live('change', function()           { 
      $("#preview").html('');
      $("#current").hide();
      $("#preview").html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif" alt="Uploading...."/>');
      $("#imageform").ajaxForm({
        target: '#preview'
           }).submit();

      });
}); 
</script>  

<form id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='ajax_file.php'>
    <input type="file" name="form_data" id="form_data" >
```

my question is i want to send bellow example hidden variable via jquery please solve my problem 
**example**

```
<input type"hidden" value="`<?php echo $value;?>`">
```

Comment: solve what? You haven't explained problem with code you have now

Answer (score 0):

[`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) has been deprecated in jQuery since v1.7, and has been removed in v1.9.

You should replace it with [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

`.on` has 2 syntaxes for binding elements, whereas `.live` only had 1.

If the element exists at the time you are binding, you do it like this:

```
`$('.element').on('click', function(){
  .......
});`
```

You can even use the shorthand:

```
`$('.element').click(function(){
.........
});`
```

If the element does not exist at the time, or new ones will be added (which is what `.live` was normally used for), you need to use "event delegation":

```
`$(document).on('click', '.element', function(){
.............
 });`
```

NOTE: You want to bind to the closest static element, not always `document`.

In the meantime, the [**jQuery Migrate plugin**](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-migrate-plugin) can be used to restore the `.live()` functionality if you upgrade your jQuery to the newest version.

Comment: I'm PHP Beginner please tell some example code for pass variables via jquery and get that value from php file

Comment: Your are not passing variables, you are trying to pass form values based on your example above. to do this you will use Ajax. There are tons of examples on here. Look up submitting forms with Ajax.